# Different spaces before links in bibliography

Tags: setspace

There are different size of spaces before links in the bibliography. My BST file and MWE are given below. How can I fix the space problem? Thank you.

[image]

My bst file: [Link 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ymtp72ccixowf1l/tez.bst?dl=0)

Alternative link for bst file: [Link 2](http://www.filedropper.com/tez)

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{r1,
  title     = {},
  author    = {{URL-1}},
  year      = {2019},
  url       = {https://earth.esa.int/web/guest/missions/esa-eo-missions/ers/mission-summary},
  note      = {2 Ocak 2019}
}

@misc{r2,
  title     = {},
  author    = {{URL-2}},
  year      = {2019},
  url       = {https://www.dlr.de/dlr/en/desktopdefault.aspx/tabid-10377/565_read-436/#/gallery/350},
  note      = {5 Ocak 2019}
}

@misc{r3,
  title     = {},
  author    = {{URL-3}},
  year      = {2019},
  url       = {http://global.jaxa.jp/projects/sat/alos/},
  note      = {5 Ocak 2019}
}

@misc{r10,
  title     = {},
  author    = {{URL-10}},
  year      = {2019},
  url       = {http://www.cosmo-skymed.it/en/index.htm},
  note      = {5 Ocak 2019}
}

@misc{r11,
  title     = {},
  author    = {{URL-11}},
  year      = {2018},
  url       = {https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-1-sar/acquisition-modes/interferometric-wide-swath},
  note      = {13 Kasım 2018}
}



\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=turkish,english,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{apacite}
%%% Same fonts for URL
\AtBeginDocument{\urlstyle{APACsame}} %
\usepackage{natbib}

%---------------------------
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref} %
\urlstyle{same}


% BEGIN
\begin{document}

\sloppy %  working with the \usepackage[none]{hyphenat} code

% CHAPTER-------------

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\cite{r1}\\
\cite{r2}\\
\cite{r3}\\
\cite{r10}\\
\cite{r11}\\
%---------------------


%BIBLIOGRAPHY---------


\setlength{\bibsep}{1\itemsep}
\bibliographystyle{tez}
\bibliography{\jobname}

%.....................

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\raggedright`?

Comment: @schtandard I can’t understand, so?

Comment: Very uneven spacing is almost always the result in a bibliography when it contains urls and is set justified (even margins on both sides).  This is because the ability to break a line within a url is very limited.  Allowing the bibliography to be set with an uneven right margin -- `\raggedright` -- is often the only sensible approach; however, many journals do not accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xurl` package will provide more possible breaking options:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{r1,
  title     = {},
  author    = {{URL-1}},
  year      = {2019},
  url       = {https://earth.esa.int/web/guest/missions/esa-eo-missions/ers/mission-summary},
  note      = {2 Ocak 2019}
}

@misc{r2,
  title     = {},
  author    = {{URL-2}},
  year      = {2019},
  url       = {https://www.dlr.de/dlr/en/desktopdefault.aspx/tabid-10377/565_read-436/#/gallery/350},
  note      = {5 Ocak 2019}
}

@misc{r3,
  title     = {},
  author    = {{URL-3}},
  year      = {2019},
  url       = {http://global.jaxa.jp/projects/sat/alos/},
  note      = {5 Ocak 2019}
}

@misc{r10,
  title     = {},
  author    = {{URL-10}},
  year      = {2019},
  url       = {http://www.cosmo-skymed.it/en/index.htm},
  note      = {5 Ocak 2019}
}

@misc{r11,
  title     = {},
  author    = {{URL-11}},
  year      = {2018},
  url       = {https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-1-sar/acquisition-modes/interferometric-wide-swath},
  note      = {13 Kasım 2018}
}



\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{xurl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=turkish,english,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{apacite}
%%% Same fonts for URL
\AtBeginDocument{\urlstyle{APACsame}} %
\usepackage{natbib}

%---------------------------
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref} %
\urlstyle{same}


% BEGIN
\begin{document}

\sloppy %  working with the \usepackage[none]{hyphenat} code

% CHAPTER-------------

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\cite{r1}\\
\cite{r2}\\
\cite{r3}\\
\cite{r10}\\
\cite{r11}\\
%---------------------


%BIBLIOGRAPHY---------


\setlength{\bibsep}{1\itemsep}
\bibliographystyle{tez}
\bibliography{\jobname}

%.....................

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, It solved the problem!